# thread-max config not read by Resin 4.0.32

Tags: java, resin

It seems to me the thread-max is always 128 no matter what I set:

Below is my config.

```
<server-default>
    <jvm-arg-line>-Xmx2048m</jvm-arg-line>
    <thread-max>64</thread-max>
</server-default>

<server id="" address="127.0.0.1" port="6800">

    <-- More settings -->

    <!-- Maximum number of threads. -->
    <thread-max>20</thread-max>

</server>
```

Am I missing something about this? How do I get the config work?

I can set the value in by code:

```
com.caucho.util.ThreadPool.setThreadMax(6);
```

Had another problem with the `com.caucho.util.ThreadPool.setThreadMax(6)`. If I debug or run through Eclipse, it is OK. However, when I run in the Cmd with ant, it reports: `[java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/caucho/util/ThreadPool` exception.

I am using Resin 4.0.32 with Java 1.6_16. Eclipse version is 4.2 if this matters.

Any suggestion or comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem,

The reason I get the exception when run with ant but didn't get it while in Eclipse IDE is because in the project, I am referring the resin.jar of version 3.0.21 and the API has been changed in resin 4.0.32 for `ThreadPool` related functions. It is no longer in `com.caucho.util`. When I debug using Eclipse, resin 3.0.21 is in the class path. But when I ran with ant, we are using resin 4.0.32.

I guess it is the same reason for the first question. I am not using the right function to read the stats.

Hope this helps.